# Redirecting Folders in Middleman's config.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, middleman

I'm using the static site generator Middleman to build my site. We currently have landing pages that we proxy via `config.rb` as such:

```
# landing page template directories to redirect
landingpage_seo_templates = Dir['source/landingpages/seo/*.erb']

# point all landingpage/seo templates to the root
landingpage_seo_templates.map! do |tpl_name|
  tpl_name = File.basename(tpl_name).gsub(/.erb$/, '')
  proxy "/#{tpl_name}/index.html", "/landingpages/seo/#{tpl_name}.html", :ignore => true
end
```

This points all of the files in a directory from `/landingpages/seo/{filename}.erb` to the `/{filename}.erb` when the site is built. However, this doesn't work for sub-folders.

My question is how would I modify this script to render the sub-folders. For examples I would like files in `/landingpages/seo/foo/{filename}.erb` to render to `/foo/{filename}.erb`

I know how to do this via `.htaccess`, however I'd like to learn how to do this via config.rb.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify your file pattern ...

`landingpage_seo_templates = Dir['source/landingpages/seo/**/*.erb']`

... you should get all `erb` templates in the `seo` tree.

You then need to modify the `tpl_name` computation (there probably is a smarter/shorter way for that):

```
# point all landingpage/seo templates to the root
landingpage_seo_templates.map! do |tpl_name|
  tpl_name = tpl_name.gsub(/.erb$/, '')
  tpl_name = tpl_name.gsub(/source\/landingpages\/seo\//, '')
  proxy "/#{tpl_name}/index.html", "/landingpages/seo/#{tpl_name}.html", :ignore => true
end
```